# Tratar con listas en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, arraylist

Tengo muy poco experiencia programando en Python y necesito ayuda para desarrollar lo siguiente:

Tengo dos listas de la siguiente manera:

```
lista1 = ['Hello', '.', "What's", 'your', 'name', '?']
lista2 = ['Hello', ',', "what's", 'Your', ',', 'name', '?']
```

Es decir tendría lo siguiente:

```
lista1[0] = Hello                         lista2[0] = Hello                       
lista1[1] = .                             lista2[1] = ,
lista1[2] = What's                        lista2[2] = what's
lista1[3] = your                          lista2[3] = Your
lista1[4] = name                          lista2[4] = ,
lista1[5] = ?                             lista2[5] = name
                                          lista2[6] = ?
```

Necesito crear una función que me compare entre la *lista1* y la *lista2* y me devuelva las posiciones en donde ha fallado la *lista2* con respecto a la *lista1* . Es decir donde los elementos de la *lista2* no son iguales o están cambiados.

El resultado que me debería dar la función es el siguiente:

```
 [(E,1), (E,2), (E,3), (E,4)].
```

Es decir que con respecto a la *lista1* la *lista2* ha fallado en las siguientes posiciones.

- En la posición 1, ya que ahí se debe encontrar un (.) en lugar de una (,).
- En la posición 2 ya que el carácter what's es diferente a What's
- En la posición 3 ya que el carácter Your es diferente a your
- Y en la posición 4 ya que ahí se debe encontrar el carácter name en lugar de (,).

Muchas Gracias por alguna ayuda o idea de como poder desarrollarlo.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo el resultado que dices que necesitas ya que realmente el único elemento que coincide según posición entre ambas listas es Hello.

Podrías utilizar zip para llevar a cabo lo que necesitas ya que por así decirlo, une múltiples iterables:

Código:

```
lista1 = ['Hello', '.', "What's", 'your', 'name', '?']
lista2 = ['Hello', ',', "what's", 'Your', ',', 'name', '?']

resultado_matches = [elemento_lista1 for elemento_lista1, elemento_lista2 in zip(lista1, lista2) if elemento_lista1 == elemento_lista2]

print(resultado_matches)
```

Resultado:

```
['Hello']
```

También podrías hacer sin comprensión de listas:

```
resultado_matches = []

for elemento_lista1, elemento_lista2 in zip(lista1, lista2):
    if elemento_lista1 == elemento_lista2:
        resultado_matches.append(elemento_lista1)

print(resultado_matches)
```

Edito:

Entiendo entonces que necesitas comparar cada posición de los elementos de la lista2 que no coincida con cada posición de los elementos de lista1. Puedes hacer esto entonces con enumerate (para obtener el índice) y zip. Ten en cuenta que la comparación se hace hasta que encuentre el último elemento de alguna de las dos listas.

Código:

```
lista1 = ['Hello', '.', "What's", 'your', 'name', '?']
lista2 = ['Hello', ',', "what's", 'Your', ',', 'name', '?']

lista_no_matches = []

for posicion, (elemento_lista1, elemento_lista2) in enumerate(zip(lista1, lista2)):
    if elemento_lista1 != elemento_lista2:
        lista_no_matches.append(('E',posicion))
```

Resultado:

```
[('E', 1), ('E', 2), ('E', 3), ('E', 4), ('E', 5)]
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda. Yo también lo había revisado así, pero no necesariamente debe coincidir por su posición. De hecho, los elementos de la _lista2_ que coinciden con los elementos de la _lista1_ son "Hello", "name" y "?".

Comment: He editado el código. Creo haber entendido lo que requieres. Saludos.